# How to show cursor shape changes with libvncclient?

Tags: c++, qt, vnc

I am developing a multi-viewer VNC client using libvncclient (part of libvncserver) and Qt.  It's been a little challenging but I finally have the app working fairly well, except that it will not show cursor shape changes from the server.  I would like to overcome this issue so I can share this software project with the world, as I do with most of my other projects.

I have tried this to make libvncclient show cursor shape changes:

```
client->appData.useRemoteCursor = false;
```

and that doesn't show cursor changes in the framebuffer.  Next, I tried handling the cursor changes myself, using:

```
client->appData.useRemoteCursor = true;
client->GotCursorShape = got_cursor_shape_change;
```

and while the `got_cursor_shape_change` callback would be called when a cursor shape change happened on the server, the buffer for the cursor image, `rcSource`, and the buffer for the cursor mask, `rcMask`, were not valid images.

I have done searches on the internet for help on this problem but resources besides the official documentation are pretty slim.  [I contacted the developers about this issue](https://github.com/LibVNC/libvncserver/issues/93), but they say that what I've tried should work.

EDIT: Also, other viewers, such as TightVNC, TigerVNC, gtk-vnc, etc are all displaying the cursor shape changes from the server, so I know it's sending the changes properly.

Does anyone have any clues as to what I should try?

Thank you in advance. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is resolved.

The problem was that a very old version of TightVNC (2.0.x) was installed on the remote machine I was testing with.  Once updated (to 2.7.x), the remote machine's cursor is visible and shape changes happen in my viewer.  The following is what is working:

`client->appData.useRemoteCursor = false;`